# bundle an ASP.Net app to be distributed as an installable on client desktops

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, software-distribution

Is it possible in anyway to bundle an ASP.Net as an installable application which users can download and install on their desktops without getting into the modalities of downloading IIS, etc & installing all that stuff.
I do understand that IIS is compulsory for asp.net so how can i bundle it as part of the setup to save the business users the complexity of iis, etc.

Comment: I think you meant to say that IIS is NOT compulsory... ?  Because it certainly isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  IIS can be entirely removed from the equation...  Basically you'll need to create your own ASP.NET host.  Dan Esposito's ASP.NET book has an entire chapter devoted to this.  There are other resources online.

Comment: TBH, i was not aware that we could run asp.net apps even without having IIS on the host. thanks a lot, i will dig a bit deeper and try to find this book as well. if you have some good technical articles in this direction, please pass them on to me.

Comment: did you mean Dino Esposito because i certainly could not find any ASP.Net book by Dan Esposito but found several by Dino Esposito